# Ordering a set in GAMS

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, gams

I'm trying to solve a problem very similar to [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2752), where I'm trying to find an optimal order. How would I actually plug this into GAMS?

It gives out a single value rather than an ordering. I could maybe have variables for each booth that correspond to their order, but I'm not sure how to prevent GAMS from selecting a booth twice.

Comment: This is not about ordering a set, that is the wrong metaphor, but rather visiting booths in a certain sequence. This is a little bit like a TSP: there we visit cities in an optimal sequence.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen - right, but I'm unclear about how to actually go about getting the order from the model. I understand in theory what TSP is, I just don't understand how it goes into GAMS